# How to create a local environment allowing to combine puppet template files and YAML files for producing properties files?

Tags: yaml, puppet, erb

I am completely new to Puppet.  Currently, we deploy our servers in different environments and the deployment group  is responsible for this. We have several puppet files and for configurable properties we use Yaml files.
So, the workflow is as follows:

We have the application.properties.puppet_template file that is converted to the application.properties file for different environments

Some properties are configurable in the application.properties.puppet_template, for example:

```
dw.message.emulate: <%= @message_emulate %>
```

The values of the configurable property are in a YAML files, for example, for default, it is in the file default_js.yaml:

```
message_emulate: true
```

or for  the dev environment it is in the file dev_js.yaml:

```
message_emulate: true
```

The seek and deploy process managed by the deployment group somehow combines a puppet_template file with a yaml file.

I see that we also have a .erb file for every server but I do not know how to apply it.

So, the question is how to create a local environment allowing to combine puppet template files and YAML files for producing properties files? I am on MacOS High Sierra

Comment: Are you asking like , you wanna create a new test environment in your local machine or ?

Comment: yes, and it is MacOS High Sierra, thank you

Answer (score 0):

For developer environment you should be using a combination of tools:

1. Vagrant
2. Beaker(Acceptance Test)
3. Puppet-Rspec
4. Hiera(Yaml Configuration Data)

Most of the heavy lifting can be done using PDK but you can use your own structure.

I used to have the following structure for my puppet development.

data/.yaml
manifests/
templates/
files/
spec/
  spec_helper.rb
  classes/
  acceptance/
     nodesets/
Rakefile